# variable in deployment job doesnt extend value

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I am having trouble getting a deployment job in a template to expand a variable it is given via a parameter. Ive used some short hand stuff below.

If you want to see the code, there is a prototype that shows the problem at https://github.com/ausfestivus/azureDevOpsPrototypes

The pipeline looks like this:

stage00

- buildjob00

  - task produces output vars (name: taskName.VAR_NAME)
- buildjob01

  - task is able to reference the variable and retrieve/display the variable value via 
    dependency notation. [dep.buildjob00.taskName.VAR_NAME]
- template:

  - parameters:

    - bunchOfVarsAsSequenceFormat:

      - var1: [dep.buildjob00.taskName.VAR_NAME]
      - var2: [dep.buildjob00.taskName.VAR_NAME]
- template contains:

  - buildjob02

    - this build job will see the variables values fine
  - deplomentjob00

    - this deploy job will see the variable names but contain empty values

Apologies if this is not well explained, hopefully the above prototype helps illustrate it better than the pseudo code above.

Comment: I meant to say I also posted this on the VSD Community as well. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/911622/deployment-variable-is-not-expanding-its-value-whe.html

Comment: Hey Ausfestivus- you will get more help here if you create a repo\prototype with just the problem and post that simplified yaml. Try to recreate the issue using the minimum number of jobs\steps in your template, with just a single variable, and a single parameter.

Comment: Also if you download the logs there will be an ```azure-pipelines-expanded.yaml```. This is the effective expanded pipeline yaml created after composition from any of your templates. You can actually create a pipeline with that yaml, and rule out the issue being related to a template.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Eric.
There is a simplified YAML at the github repo I posted. There is no simple YAML for this particular issue hence why I had to prototype it first.

Which logs are you referring to and where can they can downloaded?

Comment: No worries, to download the logs and the ```azure-pipelines-expanded.yaml``` see here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#view-and-download-logs 

On your prototype I see you put a lot of effort into it! But what I am suggesting is to give an example that just shows the problem. So only include the ```job: job00``` the ```tmpl: deploy``` and a single variable\param ```STAGE00_JOB00_BASH00_VAR00```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What a super help you shared your YAML scripts here! Otherwise, it's too difficult to understand your structure:-)*

To display the variable in `tmpl: deploy`, you need change its corresponding `dependsOn` as `job00`, rather than `templateJob`.

```
  - deployment: templateDeploy
    displayName: 'tmpl: deploy'
    continueOnError: false
    dependsOn: job00
```

Then you would see the value could display successfully:

[image]

Comment: Hey Merlin,

That sorted it out. Thank you.

For the record, [this announcement](https://dev.azure.com/mseng/AzureDevOpsRoadmap/_workitems/edit/1505234) pleases me.

I hope you guys can come up with workable and easily understood Variables handling method. The current approach is awful and hurts my head.

Comment: @Ausfestivus Hahaha, copy that. Will let our team know how it apply painful to users Just, we are trying to make them less complex:-)